# What is Dalitz decay?

Tags: particle-physics, terminology

What is Dalitz decay?

I know there are Dalitz $\pi^0 \to e^+ + e^- + \gamma$ [decay](http://www.nikhef.nl/pub/experiments/zeus/theses/wouter_verkerke/latex2html/node60.html), $w \to \pi^0  + e^+ + e^-$ decay, may be more. But is there a rule to say which decay is Dalitz and which is not?

Is there a rule to say which particle can decay by Dalitz decay and which does not?

Comment: I've found more examples: $\eta \to e^+ + e^- + \gamma$ decay, $\pi^0 \to e^+ + e^-+ e^+ + e^-$, $K_L^0 \to \mu^+ + \mu^- + \gamma$ and it seems to me that the any 3 and 4 particle decays are called Dalitz decay, since Dalitz plot can be applied to analyze them.

Comment: that first decay is not allowed by four-momenta conservation, you cannot decay one light-like particle unless its an intermediate stage of a larger decay, it needs to be either zero or two.

Comment: which first? $\eta$?

Comment: Presumably @user56771 means that there is no tree-level diagram for it. These decays certainly happen. The PDG gives the $\pi^0$ example a branching ratio of about 1% of all neutral pion decays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a really brief cursory review of the literature, I think that a Dalitz decay is a meson decay that involves two leptons in the final state, plus a photon.  A double Dalitz decay has four leptons in the final state: see [this paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fktev.fnal.gov%2Fpublic%2Fpubs%2Fktev%2Fpi0to4e%2Fpat_thesis.pdf&ei=BH0oULXsEsnZ6wHn0ICIBw&usg=AFQjCNHgWmaYV3IYp1QJU1R9w2-28y9iHQ&sig2=FIvBh12JDkKSeOZvBE9uHw) and [this paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&ved=0CGAQFjAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fpdf%2Fnucl-th%2F0702033&ei=BH0oULXsEsnZ6wHn0ICIBw&usg=AFQjCNFIsB8x5Gcwq9NRRRNrsYunP1Qb4A&sig2=xp2lJ1RzCAgn3z6d4PZmwA) for examples of the usage. The Dalitz decay is when a virtual photon from 2 photon decay of $\pi_0$ internally converts to a real lepton pair before it gets too far, and analogous thing for other meson or Higgs processes (two electrons from an internal photon conversion, plus a neutral object).

I guess that the usage comes from the kinematic decay product phase space is described by a Dalitz plot, hence the name. I don't think it's anything deep.

Comment: Sorry for my pedantry, but could you give me a reference on the definition in a reliable book? What you told was exactly my previous assumption, but I have to be sure.

Comment: @kim123: I wasn't sure about the previous answer, I just thought of the first thing that came to mind honestly, and I couldn't think of anything else. But I googled for usage, and it always is the decay of a meson into two leptons and something else. A double-Dalitz decay is into four leptons, so that establishes that the usage is for 2 lepton final states. The term Dalitz decay itself is never used without a meson as far as I saw in the search, so I changed my answer. Thanks for keeping me honest, my original answer was probably totally wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A particle's Dalitz decay means the particle decays to a massless gauge boson and two massless fermions. You can find this definition in [1308.0422](http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.0422).